# Can I somehow use a Java variable in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, java, android-studio

I have a variable called `pitchInHz` in my activity and I would like to use it in a JS function to compare it to a variable there.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Can you post more details about the situation and what you have tried so far? It's likely possible: for instance, using a WebView to [bind Android Studio code to Javascript code](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html#BindingJavaScript). However we need more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Java variables in Javascript code.

Here is how.

```
<script> 
  var java2Js = <%= pitchInHz %>

 // you can do any JS code here

</script>
```